# Using Helm Chart and Kubernetes, pass a file to the container during postStart

Tags: kubernetes, charts, configuration, initialization, kubernetes-helm

- I'm using Helm Chart, Kubernetes and containers.
- I need to pass a file to the container during postStart.
- The file will be used in the postStart script.
- The file should change from one deployment to another and should be part of the Helm Chart values.

Is the above scenario supported? Any suggestions or examples of how to implement it?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to attach a volume?

Comment: "File" isn't a Kubernetes concept really.  If it's a smallish text file, you could package it in a ConfigMap, but if it doesn't fit there, there aren't any generic straightforward options.  A more specific example would help.

Comment: David, The actual scenario is to pass a SQL dump to a DB container and to restore the DB in the postStart.
Different deployments require different SQL DB restore and it can vary at different locations, where I was hoping to get it to be part of the values.yaml.  

@Ani, An attached volume will be available after the initial install, too late for placing a file that should be used by the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below steps

1. Create a ConfigMap object using the file/script that you want to use in postStart event
2. Mount the ConfigMap as volume inside the pod
3. You should be able to access the file/script inside pod/container.